# Angular2 material selectbox

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I learn angular2  with it's material design. I  use md-select  module for material and have  code

```
 <md-select>
    <md-option value="1">1</md-option>
    <md-option value="2">2</md-option>
    <md-option value="3">3</md-option>
    <md-option value="4">4</md-option>
  </md-select>
```

But I have  [image: this error]

I use [this documetnation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/md-select)

Answer (score 1):

You're missing brackets around "value", it should be:

```
...<md-option [value]="1">1</md-option>...
```